# How to rename an image

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I have an image, `person1.png`, and four other images, `person2.png`, `person3.png`, `person5.png`, and `person4.png`. I want to rename these images in C# code. How would I do this?

Comment: I assume these are in Isolated Storage? You can't edit any files in the XAP from your code.

Comment: Actually, they're in the XAP. How would I copy them to IsolatedStorage?

Comment: I've answered with some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the PNG files are in your XAP, you can save them into your IsolatedStorage like this:

```
//make sure PNG_IMAGE is set as 'Content' build type
var pngStream= Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(PNG_IMAGE, UriKind.Relative)).Stream;

int counter;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
   using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(IMAGE_NAME, FileMode.Create, isf))
   {
      counter = 0;
      while (0 < (counter = pngStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)))
      {
             isfs.Write(buffer, 0, counter);
      }    

      pngStream.Close();

    }
 }
```

Here you can save it to whatever file name you want by changing `IMAGE_NAME`.

To read it out again, you can do this:

```
byte[] streamData;    

using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
     using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = isf.OpenFile("image.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
     {
          streamData = new byte[isfs.Length];
          isfs.Read(streamData, 0, streamData.Length);              
     }
}

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(streamData);
BitmapImage bmpImage= new BitmapImage();
bmpImage.SetSource(ms);
image1.Source = bmpImage; //image1 being your Image control
```

Comment: This gives me a NullReferenceException. I replaced PNG_IMAGE with the name of my image (in quotes), which is "/Images/Person1.png".

Comment: Where is the `NullReferenceException` thrown? Did you change the "image.png" from the reading code to "/Images/Person1.png"?

Comment: Remove the first slash in your `/Images/Person1.png` so that it's just `Images/Person1.png` and make sure its build type is `Content`

Comment: Well, it doesn't give me an exception after removing the slash, but the image doesn't change. I think that's because my code is referencing the image in the XAP, which hasn't changed at all. Could I copy the image from IsolatedStorage back to the XAP, or would I have to change my code to reference the image in IsolatedStorage?

Comment: Nope, all the files in the XAP are read only. You can copy the image into your Isolated Storage (which is what this code does). You can't copy that back to the XAP. Any changes you make to the PNG must be saved in the Isolated Storage, so anything in your code that needs the new PNG file should point to the IS and not the XAP. The XAP will only have the original, unchanged PNG.

Comment: I can't reference the image with the second block of code. VS 2010 says "The name 'data' does not exist in the current context."

Comment: Whoops, my bad. I've edited the code. Simply change `MemoryStream(data)` to `MemoryStream(streamData)`

Answer (score 2):

Use the FileInfo.MoveTo method documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.moveto.aspx). Moving a file to the same path but with a different name is how you rename files.

`FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo ("path\to\person1.png");
fInfo.MoveTo("path\to\newname.png")`

If you need to manipulate paths, use the Path.Combine method documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Whilst this will work outside the WP7 environment, you can't do this at runtime as those methods are not supported by WP7.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows Phone 7 the API methods to copy or move (rename) a file don't exist. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57z06scs(v=VS.95).aspx) You therefore have to do this yourself.

Something like:

```
var oldName = "file.old"; var newName = "file.new";

using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (var readStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(oldName, FileMode.Open, store))
    using (var writeStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(newName, FileMode.Create, store))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(readStream))
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(writeStream))
    {
        writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }

    store.DeleteFile(oldName); 
}
```

Comment: When I try this, the debugger says "IsolatedStorageException was unhandled". I'm not sure why.

Comment: This would allow you to rename files which exist in IsolatedStorage, not copy from teh xap to isolated storage, which your comments now indicate is your actual question.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload image this function auto change the image name to Full date and return the full path where the image saved and with it new name.

```
 string path = upload_Image(FileUpload1, "~/images/");
 if (!path.Equals(""))
    {
        //use the path var..
    }
```

and this is the function

```
    string upload_Image(FileUpload fileupload, string ImageSavedPath)
{
    FileUpload fu = fileupload;
    string imagepath = "";
    if (fileupload.HasFile)
    {
        string filepath = Server.MapPath(ImageSavedPath);
        String fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fu.FileName).ToLower();
        String[] allowedExtensions = { ".gif", ".png", ".jpeg", ".jpg" };
        for (int i = 0; i < allowedExtensions.Length; i++)
        {
            if (fileExtension == allowedExtensions[i])
            {
                try
                {
                    string s_newfilename = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() +
                        DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() +
                        DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + fileExtension;
                    fu.PostedFile.SaveAs(filepath + s_newfilename);

                    imagepath = ImageSavedPath + s_newfilename;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return "";
                }

            }

        }

    }
    return imagepath;

}
```

if you need more help i'll try  :)

Comment: Hi Ahmed Its better to give some explanations to the given code...Will become more helpful :)