# Dynamically load images from project folder - Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

What I want to do seems very simple, and I've done it on other platforms...

Here some context: Lets say you have 1000 small images that you want to display in a databound ListBox. You start off by including the images in your project into the folder '/images'. You set their build action to 'Content'.

Now the question: **How do you dynamically load all these images into your app at runtime?** By dynamic, I mean without having to know each name of the 1000 images.

(In case you are thinking IsolatedStorage, I've tried that. The image folder is part of your project, but isn't automatically loaded into isolatedStorage, hence you cannot, as far as I know, load the images from IsolatedStorage)

Comment: Do the images have a naming pattern or are they random? Also, you can stream images from the XAP into your Isolated Storage if you like, but may be unnecessary in this case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244150/how-to-rename-an-image/6246037#comment-7283927

Comment: I like that suggestion, but I don't know the names of the images. I guess you could say they are random. There is no pattern associated with how they are named. What I am looking for is something like - Directory.GetFiles(/images)... which would let enumerate over all files in a given directory; you could then load them all at runtime... But Directory.GetFiles is inhibited on wp7

Comment: I don't think there's a way to iterate over the XAP file without knowing the content filenames. It also can't be modified at runtime, so you'd have to add the images at compile time. Is there a reason you won't be able to know the image names? Haven't tried this, but you could set all images as `Resources` and use the `ResourceManager`. However, doing this will increase the load up time of the app.

Comment: Ok, I do know their names... but do I really want to hard code 1000 file names into my app?

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you manually type in the names. Instead, you could create a console app (non-WP7 project) which iterates through the directory and creates a text file that has a list of filenames. Simply put this text file in your XAP and read this textfile at runtime whenever you need to get your image names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get this at design time with the following T4 template:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".gen.cs" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO"#>
// <auto-generated />
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace MyAppNamespace
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private static string[] AllFilesInImagesFolder()
        {
            return new[] {
<#
            DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile), "images"));

            foreach(FileInfo file in directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                if (!file.FullName.Contains(@"\."))
                {#>
                           "<#= file.FullName.Substring(file.FullName.IndexOf("images")).Replace(@"\", "/") #>",
<#              }
            }
#>
                        };
        }
    }
}
```

It'll generate something like:

```
// <auto-generated />
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace MyAppNamespace
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private static string[] AllFilesInImagesFolder()
        {
            return new[] {
                           "images/image1.png",
                           "images/image2.png",
                           "images/image3.png",
                           "images/image4.png",
                           "images/image5.png",
                        };
        }
    }
}
```

You can obviously change the namespace and the name of the partial class as you se fit.

Comment: This looks promising... I'll try this later today when I get a chance.

Comment: After a bit of informing myself on T4 templates, this totally worked. Thanks Man. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251242.aspx

Comment: Superb. Like Matt I'd never in my life heard of a T4 template but this was exactly what I needed. Thanks for the succinct description, and thanks for introducing me to a whole new feature. Code copy-pasters like myself might want to note that there are *two* instances of the pathname in the code to alter. :)