# XNA - Scan content names

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, isolatedstorage, xna-4.0

Is there a way to scan all file names in specyfic game content folder in XNA on Windows Phone?
As far as I know Windows Phone supports only IsolatedStorage and game content is not stored there.

EOG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content files are stored in the XAP. Obviously you can access the files in the XAP, but you can't iterate through it. However, since the XAP can't be modified from your app, you should already know all the files that are in there. Is there a reason you want to scan it? If you want to scan it for design-time purposes, then the answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344865/dynamically-load-images-from-project-folder-windows-phone-7) might help.